# format column values during sql select query

Tags: php, sql

I have a table with name, gender and address.
Gender is stored as integer, 1 for male, and 2 for female.
Now when I want to show the table, in PHP, during drawing the table I check for gender with (if -- else ) and change the (1,2) output into human language ("Male","Female").

Is there a way to do this formatting in the SQL query itself ? 
so that the query result are already formatted with 'male' and 'female' values.

(I need this to create a view of the formatted table, which I need to use it in DataTable ServerSide processing, so that when I can search in the view for "male", otherwise searching in original table for male shows 0 findings, because it is "1", not "male" ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question belongs on https://stackoverflow.com/, not here.

To answer your question, you'll want to use a CASE statement:

```
CASE [gender] WHEN 1 THEN 'Male' WHEN 2 THEN 'Female' END
```